# Plot 3D group animation in WebGL playwidget in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am creating a 3D interactive model using R WebGL to plot groups of data. The script below works for plotting all groups of data, with each group having a separate color. The data contained in input.txt is only a small subset of the overall data. It is important that these be interactive (mouse control to zoom and rotate), hence why plot3D is used versus other tools.

```
library(rgl)
library(plot3D)

d <- ncol(read.table("./input.txt", header = F))
colClasses <- replace(rep("NULL", d), c(1,2,3,4), NA)
d.data <- lapply("./input.txt", read.table, header = F, colClasses = colClasses)
dval <- do.call("rbind", d.data)

df <- data.frame(dval)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "z", "y", "x")

summary(df)

plot3d(x=df$x, y=df$y, z=df$z, col = df$id, type = 's', radius = 2,
  xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z")

writeWebGL( filename="input.html" ,  width=600, height=600)
```

A small example of the input.txt file being read in to replicate this code:

```
1 0 2 3
1 1 3 3
1 2 4 4
2 5 10 15
2 6 12 16
3 10 9 10
3 11 10 11
3 12 11 12
3 13 12 13
3 14 14 14
```

I would like to extend this to plot the full data versus only a small subset. This would include having each frame as an interactive 3D plot of each group - like the output from the script above, but rather having an animation showing only 1 group each frame, with a play button to play through all the groups. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html shows an example of what I would like to do under Controls > subsetControl. The code showing how they do it:

```
rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(start = 0, stop = 3, interval = 1,
       subsetControl(1, subsets = list(
                 Setosa = setosa,
                 Versicolor = versicolor,
                 Virginica = virginica,
                 All = c(setosa, versicolor, virginica)
                 )))
```

I don't want the final image to show all the groups, and I can't use a `list` similar to their example above as the number of groups will be too many. My attempt at including their example into my script below does not work, rather just shows all the groups in the 3D plot at the same time with no button controls (identical result to the original script).

```
library(rgl)
library(plot3D)

d <- ncol(read.table("./input.txt", header = F))
colClasses <- replace(rep("NULL", d), c(1,2,3,4), NA)
d.data <- lapply("./input.txt", read.table, header = F, colClasses = colClasses)
dval <- do.call("rbind", d.data)

df <- data.frame(dval)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "z", "y", "x")

summary(df)

plotids <- with(df, plot3d(x=df$x, y=df$y, z=df$z, col = df$id, type = 's', radius = 2,
  xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z"))

rglwidget(elementId = "plot3drgl")

rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(start = 0, stop = 3, interval = 1,
       subsetControl(1, subsets = df$id
                 ))

writeWebGL( filename="input.html" ,  width=600, height=600)
```

Comment: Why can't you use a list for the `subsets` parameter?  It would simply be something like `as.list(df$id)`.  By the way, do not use `writeWebGL`.  It is deprecated.

Comment: Your code doesn't run.  It assumes there are 8 columns in the input.

Comment: I have edited the script to use 4 columns so that it will work for you. It is a simple fix by changing the ```c(1,2,7,8)``` to ```c(1,2,3,4)```. ```writeWebGL``` has been working, however is there something else I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code does what you want:

```
# First, plot everything, and save the ids of the objects in the plot
plotids <- with(df,
   plot3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, col = id, type = 's', radius = 2,
          xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z"))

# Now plot the different ids one at a time:
ids <- list()
for (i in unique(df$id)) 
  ids <- c(ids, list(with(subset(df, id == i), spheres3d(x,y,z,col=id,radius = 2))))

# Add the full dataset to the list of ids
ids <- c(ids, all = plotids["data"])

# Now plot the scene and add the playwidget.
rglwidget() %>%
  playwidget(start = 0, stop = length(ids) - 1, interval = 1,
             subsetControl(1, subsets = ids,
             ))
```

To save this in a file instead of displaying it immediately, wrap it
in `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`, or include it in an R Markdown document.  Don't use the deprecated `writeWebGL`, it knows nothing about the `playwidget` part.

Comment: I am not familiar with R Markdown. I added this to your code: ```widget <- rglwidget() %>%``` and at the bottom of the script included, ```f <- file.path(getwd(),"test.html")``` followed by ```htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget, file=f)```, and this works for saving the widget. However, the 3D plot shows all the groups in each frame, with each group having the same color, except for the last frame where each group has a different color. I would like to have the first group plotted on the first frame, the second group on the second frame, and the last group on the last frame.

Comment: It didn't show that for me.  You probably didn't execute the same code as I posted.

Comment: I forgot I had ```ids <- c(ids, all = plotids["data"])``` commented out. This code does work as I need it. I did change ```stop = length(ids) - 1``` to ```stop = length(ids) - 2``` so as to not plot the final frame with all spheres. Thank you for all your help!